# Can't copy/paste contents on Empathy

Tags: empathy

I'm using Empathy to connect to my chat accounts, but I'm unable to select and copy text with Ctrl+C shortcut. I can copy selected text if I press left mouse button and select "Copy".

This problem is happening since I was using Ubuntu Oneiric and it's happening on Precise too. Anyone know any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a problem which is being looked at by upstream developers.  See

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/459851

You already have one workaround.  Another is to highlight text and press your middle mouse button (or the scroll wheel) to paste it somewhere else.  You don't have to take any action to 'copy' it.  That is a standard function in most Ubuntu apps.

You have to note that there may be problems copying text which contain emoticons as icons.